# conditions using Ternary Operator

Tags: php

I found this code here in this forum and I am using it. It works fine except that in french the word month is mois, so it already has an s. And it wouldn't make sense with two ss.

How do I prevent it from inserting an S if a word already ends with one?
Thanks

```
function time_elapsed_string($ptime)
 {
    $etime = time() - $ptime;

    if ($etime < 1)
   {
    return '0 seconds';
   }

  $a = array( 12 * 30 * 24 * 60 * 60  =>  'an',
            30 * 24 * 60 * 60       =>  'mois',
            24 * 60 * 60            =>  'jour',
            60 * 60                 =>  'heure',
            60                      =>  'minute',
            1                       =>  'seconde'
            );

  foreach ($a as $secs => $str)
 {
    $d = $etime / $secs;
    if ($d >= 1)
    {
        $r = round($d);
        return $r . ' ' . $str . ($r > 1 ? 's' : '') . ' ago';
    }
 }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the last character of a string by using `substr()` with a substring-length of -1. So just add a condition that checks whether the word ends with an "s":

```
return $r . ' ' . $str . ($r > 1 && substr($str, -1) != 's' ? 's' : '') . ' ago';
```